# Changing SSRS report to target older SQL Server version only changes rdl file in the bin folder, BAD FORMATTING

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, rdl

VS2017 initially built the report targeting SQL Server 2016 but we only use 2008 currently. When I change the properties to target an older version of SQL Server it appears to only alter the rdl file in the bin folder after the report is built but does not alter the rdl file in the solution root directory. I want the rdl file in the solution root directory to reflect the SQL Server version changes.

I'm fully aware I can grab the one in the bin folder but the one located there has no formatting and is all on one line. I really don't want to check something this awful looking into source.

Comment: I have encountered this problem.  It is something that is very awkward for deployments.  Did you report it to Microsoft?  If so, what site?  Thanks much

Comment: @JosephDoggie Sorry for the late response.  I did not put in a report to Microsoft.  We have went ahead and updated to 2016 so it has no longer been an issue for us.